# How get the returned value of d3.ease?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 Version 3 and I am trying to use d3's ease function for animation. According to the function's definition it has a return value

```
function ease(type: 'cubic-in'): (t: number) => number;
```

I am expecting a number as the return value to use it in my computation. But, now how can I cast the return value of the ease function to a number.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I edited the question's title to better explain what, I believe, is your problem. If I'm wrong, just roll it back.

Comment: That was absolutely right. Thanks a ton. @GerardoFurtado :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d3.ease` already returns a number.

You just need to pass the value you want to `d3.ease`:

```
d3.ease(type)(value);
```

Here is a demo with `"cubic-in"`, as in your question:

```js
function ease(value) {
  return d3.ease("cubic-in")(value);
}

console.log("ease for 0.1: " + ease(4));
console.log("ease for 0.5: " + ease(0.5));
console.log("ease for 0.8: " + ease(0.8));
console.log("ease for 0.95: " + ease(0.95));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that the passed value and the returned value are between `0` and `1`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_ease):

> An easing function takes the current parameterized time value `t` in the domain `[0,1]`, and maps it to another value in a similar range.

Comment: could you please guide me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472246/how-to-use-timer-in-d3-v3 Thank you.