# How to use timer in d3 V3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timer

I have a function `triggerWave()` which makes the points on the canvas animate in the wave form. I am using `d3.ease('quad-in')` for easing and I would like to use `d3.timer()` to make the `triggerWave()` function call over `200ms` timeframe. I am out of luck in finding the tutorials or examples on d3.timer.

```
triggerWave() {
  //function logic
  let count = 0;
  let xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([1,2]); // want the value to change from 1 to 2.
  let zScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]); // 200 ms.
  let value = xScale(d3.ease('quad-in')(zScale(count)));
  if(count < 200){
   count++;
   d3.timer(() => triggerWave());
  } else {
    // do something
  }
  this.wave.next({currentFrame: value});
}
```

When I call `d3.timer()` as above, the `triggerWave()` function gets called infinite times and never stops. I want to manipulate or control the time. In my case, I want the timer() to be triggered for `200ms`.

How can I understand how to use the `d3.timer()` function?

Comment: Tums, I wrote an answer and, only after posting it, I noticed that you're using D3 v3. Unfortunately, there is no `d3.timeout` in v3, but you can do the same approach proposed in my answer with vanilla JS, that is, `setTimeout`: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ffv3r5gn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 3, there is no `d3.timer.stop()` function. You have to return `true` after a certain period of time to stop the timer.

In Gerardo's answer, he explained fabulously how to use the `d3 timeout` which would be a valid solution to your problem i.e., to call the function over and over for a certain period of time. But looking at your comments on Gerardo's answer, I think you are looking for something else.

Here's what I came up with and I think this is what you are looking for:

You can create an another function called as `activateTriggerWave()` which will be invoked on the button click and inside this function, you can call your `triggerWave()` method using the `d3 timer`.

```
function activateTriggerWave() {
  d3.timer(elapsed => {
  this.triggerWave();
  if(elapsed >= 200){
    return true; // this will stop the d3 timer. 
  }
});
}

triggerWave() {
 // here you can do whatever logic you want to implement.
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, up. But why the typescript?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you :)  I have been writing too much typescript with Angular 4 and I just wrote it without looking if it was JS or TS. ;) Will add a JS version in the edit. But I think, only the type-casting goes and the function keyword would be added. Isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

(**EDIT**: I totally and completely missed the huge, big "**V3**" which is right there, in the title of the question. Sorry. I'll keep this answer here as reference for v4 users)

Since you are calling `triggerWave` inside the `triggerWave` function itself, you don't need `d3.timer`, but `d3.timeout` instead. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/master/README.md#timeout), `d3.timeout`:

> Like timer, except the timer automatically stops on its first callback. A suitable replacement for setTimeout that is guaranteed to not run in the background. The callback is passed the elapsed time.

Also, pay attention to the fact that you are reseting `count` every time the function runs, which will not work. Set its initial value *outside* the function.

Here is a demo with those changes. I'm calling the function every 200 ms, until `count` gets to `50`:

```js
var p = d3.select("p")
var count = 0;

triggerWave();

function triggerWave() {
  p.html("Count is " + count)
  if (count < 50) {
    count++;
    d3.timeout(triggerWave, 200)
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

You can also keep track of the total elapsed time, using the argument passed to `triggerWave` by `d3.timeout`:

```js
var p = d3.select("p")
var count = 0;
var elapsed = 0;
var format = d3.format(".2")

triggerWave();

function triggerWave(t) {
  elapsed = t ? elapsed + t : elapsed;
  p.html("Count is " + count + ", and the elapsed time is " + format(elapsed/1000) + " seconds")
  if (count < 50) {
    count++;
    d3.timeout(triggerWave, 200)
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Since you are using D3 v3, and as there is no `d3.timeout` in v3, you can do the same approach using vanilla JavaScript: `setTimeout`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var p = d3.select("p")
var count = 0;

triggerWave();

function triggerWave() {
  p.html("Count is " + count)
  if (count < 50) {
    count++;
    setTimeout(triggerWave, 200)
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Gerardo, Thanks a lot for a great answer. In your answer you mentioned that I am calling my function triggerWave inside the triggerWave function itself and hence I don't need d3.timer. I actually achieved the animation using the requestAnimationFrame by calling the triggerWave function inside the rAF(() => triggerWave()) like this. But, instead I want to use d3.timer to achieve the same. So, with d3.timer, should I be calling the function from outside? And if yes how can I do that and how to stop the function in this scenario. It gets into an infinite loop :(

Comment: And also, I am calling the function from inside the same function because, the `triggerWave` function is being called on a button click. i.e., on the button click, the function is getting initiated and then to make the loop, I am using `d3.timer` inside and calling the function again and again. I am not really sure how I could trigger the `d3.timer` on the button click and give my function as a call back and make it return true to stop it. This is what I am struggling with and unable to find resources online.

Answer (score -1):

I use d3.js [v3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md), and the timer can be stopped by any user action. In the d3.js docs it is shown to use it as:

```
d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
  console.log(elapsed);
  return elapsed >= 1000;
});
```

I have few examples in which the animation is *forever* and there is no reason to set a limit on it. Checking the standalone [d3.timer](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer) which comes with a `stop()`, I found  that it behaves quite slow comparing it with the default timer included in the v3 toolset, probably for some version incompatibility.

The solution is use is to:

```
var timer_1_stop=false;
```

set it as global var accesible from the page scope. Then the timer:

```
const run=function(){
  //...
  d3.timer(function() {
    voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi(points).map(function(cell) { return bounds.clip(cell); });
    path.attr("d", function(point, i) { return line(resample(voronoi[i])); });

    return timer_1_stop;
  });
}

const stopVoro=function(){
  timer_1_stop=true;
}
```

It allows to do:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(<ul>
      <li><span onClick={()=>{stopVoro()}}>StopVoro</span></li>
    </ul>)
  }
}
```